# How to use model data in a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have `HomeController` and `Index` method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
         return View();
    }   
}
```

It returns this page:

```
<form asp-controller="Player" asp-action="VideoPlayer" method="post">
                    <div class="demo-btns">
                        <div class="info">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <p><input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Name:" size="18" /></p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="roomCode" placeholder="Code of the room:" size="18" /></p>
                        <input type="submit" class="modal__trigger2" value="Join Room" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

PlayerController:

```
public class PlayerController : Controller
{
     public static RoomData roomData = new RoomData();

     public IActionResult VideoPlayer(string userName, string roomCode)
     {
         roomData.UserName = userName;
         roomData.RoomCode = roomCode;
         return View();
     }
}
```

I'd like to show `userName` and `roomCode` on another page that is why I use PlayerController and VideoPlayer action

```
@using Watch.Models;
<div class="content-box-center-monitor">
   <div>Model?.RoomData></div> 
   <div>Model?.RoomCode</div> 
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. My final html looks like this and I don't know why:

```
<div class="content-box-center-monitor">
   <div></div> // no data 
   <div></div> // no data
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the model to the view

```
public class PlayerController : Controller
{
     public static RoomData roomData = new RoomData();

     public IActionResult VideoPlayer(string userName, string roomCode)
     {
         roomData.UserName = userName;
         roomData.RoomCode = roomCode;
         return View(roomData);
     }
}
```

Then in VideoPlayer page

```
@model RoomData;
<div class="content-box-center-monitor">
   <div>Model?.UserName</div> 
   <div>Model?.RoomCode</div> 
</div>
```